Configuring VLAN Trunk on JunOS
I have a Juniper EX-4300-48P and I was trying to test out connecting it to a TP-LINK TL-SG108E and the intended network flow is as follows:
EX-4300-48P Interface ge-0/0/0 set to trunk VLAN 121,125,126 -> TL-SG108E Port 1
TL-SG108E Port 1 should be manageable via VLAN 121 but trunk VLAN 121,125,126
TL-SG108E Port 2 accesses VLAN 125
TL-SG108E Port 3 accesses VLAN 126

I configured two different setups on the EX-4300-48P (Neither of which worked)-
Version 1:
ge-0/0/0 {
    flexible-vlan-tagging;
    encapsulation extended-vlan-bridge;
    unit 121 {
        vlan-id 121;
    }
    unit 125 {
        vlan-id 125;
    }
    unit 126 {
        vlan-id 126;
    }
}

Version 2:
ge-0/0/0 {
  unit 0 {
    family ethernet-switching {
      interface-mode trunk;
      vlan {
        members [ v121 v125 v126 ];
      }
    storm-control default;
    }
  }
}

So far I configured this on the TL-SG108E-
Port 1:

VLAN Member for VLAN 121,125,126
Tagged for VLAN 121,125,126
PVID = 121

Port 2:

VLAN member for VLAN 125
Untagged VLAN 125
PVID = 125

Port 3:

VLAN member for VLAN 126
Untagged VLAN 126
PVID = 126



Anyone have any ideas as to why when I connect the trunk port I don't even see any packet traffic on ge-0/0/0 but have a blinking activity light on both ends? Also I don't even see the TP-LINK TL-SG108E on the network?

Unfortunately, your TP-Link is off-topic here. For a device to be on-topic, the manufacturer must offer optional, paid support, and TP-Link does not offer that for that switch.
